# XBee S2C with Python: Receive does not work

Tags: python, xbee

I work with an XBee S2C mounted on a Sparkfun explorer at COM4 of my laptop. If I run the attached code, I will only see the Tx-lines, but I won't get the Rx-lines and the "Hello Word". The access from the PC to the COM-port seems not to be a problem, because the port is blocked, if I try to get access by another application.

```
from time import sleep

if __name__ == "__main__": 
xbee = XBee.XBee("COM4")  # Your serial port name here

# A simple string message
sent = xbee.SendStr("Hello World")
sleep(0.25)
Msg = xbee.Receive()
if Msg:
    content = Msg[7:-1].decode('ascii')
    print("Msg: " + content)

# A message that requires escaping
xbee.Send(bytearray.fromhex("7e 7d 11 13 5b 01 01 01 01 01 01 01"))
sleep(0.25)
Msg = xbee.Receive()
if Msg:
    content = Msg[7:-1]
    print("Msg: " + xbee.format(content))
```

I see the problem only with Python, not with XCTU. The same situation occurs, if I send data from an other XBee to the XBee mounted on the Sparkfun USB-explorer. For me it is not clear what is going wrong (python code, hardware) and I would be happy to get some help to solve the problem and to get  hints for a tutorial or book according XBee and Python. Thank you very much for your support. 
Regards Daniel

Comment: sound like not python error, explore and connection is different. Device config, additional drivers etc. have't idea which is missed !

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment. Do you have any idea, what to check to solve the problem? Do I need any specific driver for Python-XBee? Is any change in the XBee-configuration (XCTU) necessary to work with Python? Is there any specific tutorial available?